# Listening to port that Windows app uses results in EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js

I have a Windows application that sends/receives TCP messages on a certain port. I hooked up the [simple echo example](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.1/api/all.html#net.Server) on the Node.js website but I get the EADDRINUSE error.

I assume this is because my app is using that port.

What I was trying to do is to listen to that port and then hook a browser up to listen to what the server is sending out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, think I got it working:

```
var sys = require("sys"),
    net = require("net");

var client = net.createConnection(10100);
client.setEncoding("UTF8");

client.addListener("connect", function() {
  sys.puts("Client connected.");
  // close connection after 2sec
  setTimeout(function() {
    sys.puts("Sent to server: close");
    client.write("close", "UTF8");
  }, 2000);
});

client.addListener("data", function(data) {
  sys.puts("Response from server: " + data);
  if (data == "close") client.end();
});

client.addListener("close", function(data) {
  sys.puts("Disconnected from server");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to intercept data sent to and from an applicaiton, I would recommend using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). If you want to capture this data from an applicaiton, I would recommend you use [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org/).

Comment: I'm trying to make a web app and thought node.js and websockets would be the way to go

Comment: It sounded like you're trying to intercept traffic from someone else's app. If this is not the case, you don't need these tools. You will not be able to listen on the same port as another application.

Comment: I write the Windows app as well and I have added an answer that allows me to connect to the windows server app.